# RuntimeError: received 0 items of ancdata when sharing sockets between processes

Tags: python, sockets, multiprocessing

Here is the minimal code I can imagine without error handling, graceful exit etc.

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3.5
import multiprocessing, socket, traceback
from multiprocessing import reduction

def loop(pipe):
    while True:
        try:
            c = socket.fromfd(reduction.recv_handle(pipe), socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
            c.sendall('HTTP/1.1 200 OK\r\nContent-Length: 6\r\nContent-Type: text/plain\r\n\r\nhello\n'.encode())
            c.shutdown(socket.SHUT_WR)
            c.close()
        except: print(traceback.format_exc())

if __name__ == '__main__':
    pipe_recv, pipe_send = multiprocessing.Pipe()

    proc = multiprocessing.Process(target=loop, args=(pipe_recv,))
    proc.start()

    s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
    s.setsockopt(socket.SOL_SOCKET, socket.SO_REUSEADDR, 1)
    s.bind(('localhost', 9000))
    s.listen()

    while True:
        conn, addr = s.accept()
        reduction.send_handle(pipe_send, conn.fileno(), proc.pid)
```

I can `curl` it:

```
curl -v http://localhost:9000/
*   Trying 127.0.0.1...
* Connected to localhost (127.0.0.1) port 9000 (#0)
> GET / HTTP/1.1
> Host: localhost:9000
> User-Agent: curl/7.47.0
> Accept: */*
>
< HTTP/1.1 200 OK
< Content-Length: 6
< Content-Type: text/plain
<
hello
* Connection #0 to host localhost left intact
```

It works pretty fine when I have one or a couple of loop-ed curl-s, but if I create a lot of 'client' or simply use apache benchmark, for example, the script crashes with:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/tmp/this-is-my-script", line 8, in loop
    c = socket.fromfd(reduction.recv_handle(pipe), socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.5/multiprocessing/reduction.py", line 181, in recv_handle
    return recvfds(s, 1)[0]
  File "/usr/lib/python3.5/multiprocessing/reduction.py", line 160, in recvfds
    len(ancdata))
RuntimeError: received 0 items of ancdata
```

I spent a lot of time trying understand this with no luck. So I gave up and asking this question. The `reduction` module is not even documented in `3.5`. Does that mean that I shouldn't use it?

If no - I don't see any other possibility to share the socket between processes, are there any?

If yes - what I miss?

Comment: According https://docs.python.org/2/library/socket.html?highlight=shutdown#socket.socket.shutdown , `socket.shutdown(socket.SHUT_WR)` only closes half of the connection. This may have something to do with your hangs.

Comment: Yes it is, but other half has to be closed by client, otherwise, socket will remain in TIME_WAIT state on the server.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally!

1. No need to call `socket.fromfd()`. My code was based on [this gist](https://gist.github.com/josiahcarlson/3723597), not sure about python2, but in 3.5 it definetely leads to unneeded socket duplicate creation which in its turn remains in TIME_WAIT which can be avoided if call `socket.socket()` directly.

*fromfd() source:*

```
def fromfd(fd, family, type, proto=0):
    nfd = dup(fd)
    return socket(family, type, proto, nfd)
```

2. Socket must be closed after transferring on sender side according to [this IBM article](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/mobile/#!/ssw_ibm_i_71/rzab6/xdescriptors.htm)
3. Also, unconditional closing the socket in subproccess was leading apache benchmark to hang. It works without issues without `close()` at all.

So the final version is below. It's not multiprocessed actually so it would fail apache benchmark test with `-c` argument. But that is out of scope of the question.

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3.5
import multiprocessing, socket, traceback
from multiprocessing import reduction

def loop(pipe_recv):
    while True:
        try:
            conn = socket.socket(fileno=reduction.recv_handle(pipe_recv))
            conn.sendall('HTTP/1.0 200 OK\r\nContent-Length: 6\r\nContent-Type: text/plain\r\n\r\nhello\n'.encode())
            conn.shutdown(socket.SHUT_WR)
        except: print(traceback.format_exc())

if __name__ == '__main__':
    pipe_recv, pipe_send = multiprocessing.Pipe()

    proc = multiprocessing.Process(target=loop, args=(pipe_recv,))
    proc.start()

    s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
    s.setsockopt(socket.SOL_SOCKET, socket.SO_REUSEADDR, 1)
    s.bind(('localhost', 9000))
    s.listen(100)

    while True:
        conn, addr = s.accept()
        reduction.send_handle(pipe_send, conn.fileno(), proc.pid)
        conn.close()
```

Comment: "Socket must be closed after transferring on the sender side" - not only according "to an IBM article" but http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17297810/can-socket-objects-be-shared-with-pythons-multiprocessing-socket-close-does as well.

Comment: @ivan_pozdeev: I just realized that in this specific case, `close()` can be elided since `conn` is garbage collected immediately. But you are correct, that was discussed on SO and I've missed it.