# How do I share a list across processes with SyncManager in Python without passing references

Tags: python, ipc, python-multiprocessing

In python, the multiprocessing module provides managers that can generate shared lists/dicts between processes.

However, I'm having an issue using these shared objects if the processes accessing the manager are not child processes, but are instead connecting to the manager via `Manager.connect`.

Here's a very basic example: I'm trying to create a shared list that can be accessed by a group of processes. For this example, I'm just launching this same code twice in two terminal windows:

```py
import os, time
from multiprocessing.managers import SyncManager
            
def main() -> None:
    print(f"I am process {os.getpid()}")
    print(f"Starting proxy server...")
 
    manager = SyncManager(address=("127.0.0.1", 8000), authkey=b"noauth")
    try:
        manager.start() # will start the sync process if it doesn't exist
    except:
        manager.connect() # if it does already exist, connect to it instead
 
    print(f"Proxy server started/connected")
 
    # would like to generate a shared list that each process can access.
    sharedList = manager.list() # this generates a new list, so each process gets their own, which is not what I want
 
    sharedList.append(os.getpid())
 
    time.sleep(20)
 
if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Pythons [documentation on using remote managers](https://docs.python.org/3/library/multiprocessing.html#using-a-remote-manager) seems similar to what I'm looking for, but there's no information on how to get a `Manager.list` or `Manager.dict` shared.

Note: I'd also be perfectly happy sharing a namespace object.

Comment: My thought is that you have to establish some sort of a communication channel between the two Managers.  This SO question seems to explain how to do that:  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4467626/python-sharing-a-network-socket-with-multiprocessing-manager.  Once you've done that, I'm wondering if you can have the manager on one side create a shared list and then send it (a reference to it really) over the communication channel to the other Manager.  The other Manager should then create a proxy for that object that you can use on that side.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's how I ended up solving the problem. You need to spawn a manager process, that is in possession of the shared list, manually.

```py
import multiprocessing
from multiprocessing import process
import os, time, sys
from multiprocessing.managers import SyncManager, ListProxy
from queue import Queue

class SharedStorage(SyncManager):
    pass

def ManagerProcess():
    sys.stdout = open(os.devnull, 'w') 
    sys.stderr = open(os.devnull, 'w') 

    l = list()

    SharedStorage.register('get_list', lambda: l, ListProxy)
    try: 
        ss = SharedStorage(address=("127.0.0.1", 8000), authkey=b"noauth")
        ss.get_server().serve_forever()
    except OSError:
        # failed to listen on port - already in use.
        pass

def main() -> None:
    print(f"I am process {os.getpid()}")
    print(f"Starting proxy server...")

    mainProcess = multiprocessing.Process(target=ManagerProcess, daemon=True)
    mainProcess.start()

    SharedStorage.register('get_list')
    manager = SharedStorage(address=("127.0.0.1", 8000), authkey=b"noauth")
    manager.connect()

    print(f"Proxy server started/connected")

    # required - see https://bugs.python.org/issue7503
    multiprocessing.current_process().authkey = b"noauth"

    # get reference to the shared list object
    shared_list = manager.get_list()

    shared_list.append(os.getpid())

    for i in shared_list:
        print(i)

    time.sleep(20)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

This can be run several times safely, as manager processes spawned by later processes will exit after they cannot listen on the port.